# Time wrong ubuntu studio 16.04

Tags: 16.04, time

It is a fresh full clean install of Ubuntu Studio 16.04 on a Toshiba Satellite 855C - no dual boot or virtual machine.

I cannot change the time in the settings, it *magically* switches back!

I do not have `ntp` support, do not need it.

What is going wrong here, how can I correct my time settings?

Comment: To be honest - i would go for NTP - as it is the solution to keep your clock in time for the forseeable future.

Comment: So is the offset between your real local clock time and the local time displayed by your computer always constant and a multiple of an hour (or half an hour)? In that case, it looks strongly like a time zone misconfiguration. Also, what is the BIOS time?

Comment: Bios is correct and flash updated.  I have exactly 12 hours as an offset.  I've tried the ntp commands exhaustively, date, tzdata, ntp pools, battery ok, sys and bios will not write to each other!  I am currently in  GMT -6